# Can't get circle radius after circleRedim in angular2 google-maps

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular-google-maps

I don't know how to get the circle radius after resize

**First approach**

.html

```
    <map-circle
    (radiusChanged) = circleRedim()
    [center]="center" 
    [options] = circleOptions >
   </map-circle>
```

.ts

```
circleRedim(){ //<-void
 console.log(?) //<- I vould like to log the new circle radius
}
```

**Second approach**

.html

```
<map-circle #circleRef
[center]="center" 
[options] = circleOptions >
</map-circle>
```

.ts

```
@ViewChild('circleRef') circleRef: google.maps.Circle;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log(this.circleRef); //<- circle ref isn't an istance of  google.maps.Circle
  }
```

[circleRef contains an ElementRef](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6wx5t.png)

Answer (score 0):

[I found a solution here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/23771#issuecomment-945118742)

```
<map-circle
(radiusChanged) = radiusChanged()
[center]="center" 
[options] = circleOptions >
</map-circle>

@ViewChild(MapCircle) circle: MapCircle;
radiusChanged(){
    if(this.circle){
      console.log(this.circle.getRadius());
    }
}
```